# could not cast value of type error Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode

I keep getting the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'my project goes here' (0x10f5e3f28) to
> 'UINavigationController' (0x7fff897de6f0). (lldb)

I get a `SIGABRT` error when I click on the button associated with this code.

Any ideas greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func anonymousTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
  print("anonymous tapped")
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let ChatVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatVC") as! UINavigationController
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = ChatVC
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code.  The error says you have an instance of your own class when a `UINavigationController` is expected.

Comment: this simple mean that controller in storuyboard with identifier "ChatVC" is not a `UINavigationController` - please check your storyboard and identifier of navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that controller in the storyboard with identifier "ChatVC" is not a `UINavigationController` - please check your storyboard and identifier of a navigation controller.

[image]